# Grouping Tile view in PhoneJS

Tags: phonejs, devextreme

I am trying to show products from database into tileview item in devexpress phonejs. Successfully I can load items from datasource into tileview but I would like to group items by the category name and really dont have any idea howto do it. Any help will be appreciated.

JS Code

```
return {
    sale: sale,
    departmansSource: {
        store: PosApplication.db.Departmans,
        select: ["DepartmanID", "DepartmanName"]
    },
    categoriesSource: {
        store: PosApplication.db.Categories,
        select: ["CategoryID", "CategoryName"]
    },
    productsSource: {
        store: PosApplication.db.Products,
        filter: ["DepartmanID","=", 2],
        select: ["ProductID", "ProductName", "DepartmanID", "DepartmanName", "CategoryID", "CategoryName"]
    },
    approversSource: {
        store: PosApplication.db.Approvers,
        select: ["ApproverId", "ApproverName"]
    },
    handleSave: handleSave,
    handleCancel: handleCancel,
    viewShown: handleViewShown,
    notifiy: notifiy
};
```

Html Code

```
<div id="urunlertile" data-bind="dxTileView: { height: '550', dataSource: productsSource, itemClickAction: notifiy, baseItemHeight: 70, baseItemWidth: 150, itemMargin: 3,  }">
            <div data-options="dxTemplate:{name:'item'}">                    

                <p><span data-bind="text: $data.CategoryName"></span></p>
                <p><span data-bind="text: $data.ProductName"></span></p>
                </div>                           
            </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use postProcess callback to group/sort data in your dataSource.

See doc with example:
http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Howto/Data_Layer/Data_Layer?version=14_1#Data_Layer_Data_Layer_Reading_Data_Data_Transformation_Post_Processing

Note that dxTileView doesn't support displaying grouped data out of box. Having grouped data like

```
[{ key: "Category1", items: [{ name: "Product1" }, ...], ...]
```

you could put nested dxTileView in item template to display products for each category.